# Hyper-V networking nested within esxi host

Tags: hyper-v, esxi

Setup:

Esxi 5.1 host running:

Windows Server 2008 data center VM with Hyper-V role

Windows Server 2008 R2 standard 64bit VM hosted by hyper-V

Problem:

I'm trying to get network connectivity between my 2 windows servers but so far have been unsuccessful. I've tried both an external and internal network and have been unsuccessful in getting the machines to speak to one another.
 Has anyone else tried to test networking with hyper-v while nested within an esxi host? I know there are some quirks with this setup so this may just be one of those things that doesnt work.

Comment: Please try to write more details. How did you setup the networking on both machines, on Hyper-V, on ESXi? How did you troubleshoot it (ping, arp etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this, but in theory it should work.
1. Are they on the same network? 
2. Can each OS ping a common network resource like a router, printer or another PC? Note: use a control for this test, like your desktop or laptop. Something that you know can ping other resources on the network.
3. For testing, disable all firewalls. This includes windows and esxi firewalls.

Comment: So after installing and reinstalling I was able to give my hyper-v VM's internet access. however, I've still been able to get either a private or internal network to work with the VM's